# How to solve $\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have a problem with the following integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\mathrm dx$$
My work:

Let $x=\sec (t)$ and $\mathrm dx=\sec(t)\tan(t)\mathrm dt$

$$\int \frac{\sec t\tan t}{\sec^2t\sqrt{\tan^2t}}\,\mathrm dt=\int \cos t\,\mathrm dt=\sin t +c$$
Actually I should write $\int sgn(t)\cos(t)\,dt$ but given that $t=\sec^{-1}x$ is always positive i can omit it **(Am i right?)**.

Now I have

$$\sin t+c = \sin (\sec^{-1}x)+c = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{|{x}|}+c$$

but the solution in my book is $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C$$

Where am i wrong?

A similar exercise is the following:
$$\int\frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\mathrm dx$$
where using the same substitution i have to solve:
$$\int \cos^2t\,\mathrm dt=\frac12\sec^{-1}x+\frac14\sin(2\sec^{-1}x)=\frac12\sec^{-1}x+\frac12\sin(\sec^{-1}x)\cos(\sec^{-1}x)$$
where the final form is:
$$\frac12\sec^{-1}x+\frac12\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{|{x}|x}+c$$
instead in my book the solution is
$$\frac12\sec^{-1}x+\frac12\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2}+c$$
Thanks to all.

Comment: It's $\operatorname{sgn}(\tan t)$, not $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Right! Thanks! Are there any consequences?

Comment: Also, here is a general consideration: an integral of an even function is an odd function (plus a constant).

Comment: Ofc there are! It changes everything and i have the correct result, am i right? Because the solution will be $\sin ( \sec^{-1} x)$ for $x \ge 1$ and $\sin (\sec^{-1} x)$ for $x \le -1$. In both case is $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$. Right? @AlexanderBurstein

Comment: Yep. But I think you need a minus sign in the second case in front of the $\sin$, too.

Comment: I think both. $ - \sin (\sec^{-1} x)$ for $x \le -1$ because $\tan (\sec^{-1} x)$ is positive for $x > 1$ and negative for $x<-1$  @AlexanderBurstein

Comment: Perfect! @AlexanderBurstein

Comment: _"... but the solution in my book is $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C$. Where am i wrong?"_
//
"My" CAS returns $\displaystyle \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$ -- where is the failure?

Comment: @m-stgt what is "CAS"?

Comment: A, sorry, I forgot to link: [Reduce CAS](http://www.reduce-algebra.com), they even offer an [online option](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/web-reduce/about.php?start). CAS spells "computer algebra system".

Comment: if "CAS" is a calculator there is no error because you can split that fraction in $\frac{x}{x} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$. The first term is $1$, a costant term that you can incorporate into the costant "+C".. however i don't know why your calculator does this. @m-stgt

Answer (score 3):

The answer in the book is **correct**.
When we consider the substitution $x=\sec t,$ we have to emphasis the domain of the secant function as below:

Let $$x=\sec t,\textrm{  for any }t \in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right],$$
then $$
\sec ^{-1} x=t \in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right] \Rightarrow \sin t=\sin(\sec^{-1}x)>0.
$$
Hence $$
\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x =\sin t+C=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C
$$
Similar argument for the second integral.

Comment: I don't really understand. You wrote $\sin t >0$ for all $t$, Perfect. But in the last equivalence you have $\sin t = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$ where the second term is not always positive.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can set that $x = \cosh(u)$, where $x \geq 1$.

Then one gets the desired result as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2} - 1}} & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(\cosh(u))}{\cosh^{2}(u)\sqrt{\cosh^{2}(u) - 1}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\sinh(u)}{\cosh^{2}(u)\sinh(u)}\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\cosh^{2}(u)}\\\\
& = \int\text{sech}^{2}(u)\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \tanh(u) + C\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2 } - 1}}{x} + C
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatively**, we can use another substitution $y=\frac{1}{x}  $.
Firstly, we can divide 2 cases: $$
x^2-1 \geqslant 0 \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ A.  } x\leqslant-1 \text { or } \textrm{ B. } x \geqslant 1
$$
$\textrm{ A.  } x\leqslant-1$, $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}-1}} \frac{d y}{-y^2}  \\
& =\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} d y \\
& =-\sqrt{1-y^2}+C \\
& =-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+C \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C \quad ( \textrm{ As }\sqrt{x^2}=-x)
\end{aligned}
$$

$\textrm{ B. } x \geqslant 1, $

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}-1}} \frac{d y}{-y^2}  \\
& =-\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} d y \\
& =\sqrt{1-y^2}+C \\
& =\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+C 
\end{aligned}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx$:

Let $t= \frac{1}{x}, $ $dx= \frac{-dt}{t^2}$
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx =\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}- 1}} dt= \int\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt = \sqrt{1-t^2}+C =  \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+C$$

---

For $\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx$:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx=\int\frac{1-x^2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx + \int\frac{x^2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx  $$

$$=\int\frac{-\sqrt{x^2 - 1}  }{x^3} dx + \int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx$$

Now the integral $ \int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx$ is a famous one and it is $\operatorname{arcsec}{|x|}+C$

Integration by parts for $\int\frac{-\sqrt{x^2 - 1}  }{x^3} dx$ gives us $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left( \int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}dx\right)$

So the answer is
$$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{arcsec}{|x|}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2}\right) +C$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another alternative. Insert the parameter, $a$ such that

$$I(a) = \int{\frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{a\cdot x^2 - 1}}}{dx}
\\= \int{\int{\frac{-1}{2(a\cdot x^2 - 1)^{3/2}}}{da}}{\,dx} = \int{\int{\frac{-1}{2(a\cdot x^2 - 1)^{3/2}}}{dx}}{\,da}$$

Now its simpler without the additional $x^2$. Applications of chain/power rule for both integrals give:

$$I(a) = \int{\int{\frac{-1}{2(a\cdot x^2 - 1)^{3/2}}}{dx}}{\,da}
\\= \int{\frac{x}{2\sqrt{a\cdot x^2 - 1}}}{\,da}
\\= \frac{\sqrt{a\cdot x^2 - 1}}{x} + C$$

where,

$$I(1) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{x} + C$$